# how to change post and upload file size in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

What is the maximum size that can be posted or uploaded? When I try to upload 7 MB image file, I get an error where all the input fields become undefined index in the controller. Is this the file size or what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your upload system working fine ?Is it work for small size file? Did you given validation ?You should provide some code what you have tried .

Comment: Check your php.ini for `upload_max_filesize`.